# How to get rid of the indexed count of arrays within an array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, json

Hello I have an array that consists of two other arrays within it using the following code:

```
    foreach($relations as $rel){
        $data[$i]["relationTo"] = $rel["name"];
        $data[$i]["relation"] = $rel["relation"];
        $i = $i+1;
    }
    foreach($relations as $rel){
        $children[$i]["id"] = $rel["id2"];
        $children[$i]["name"] = $rel["sname"];
        $children[$i]["data"] = $data;
        $i = $i+1;
    }
    foreach($relations as $rel){
        $relationArray[$i]["id"] = $rel["id"];
        $relationArray[$i]["name"] = $rel["name"];
        $relationArray[$i]["children"] = $children;
        $i = $i+1;
    }
```

When I print this out using:

```
print_r($relationArray);
```

It prints the following:

```
Array ( [2] => Array ( [id] => 4 [name] => Albaraa [children] => 
Array ( [1] => Array (      [id] => 5 [name] => Sadi [data] => 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [relationTo] => Albaraa [relation] => Father ) ) ) ) ) )
```

I am using json_encode and I need it to be output in json a certain way not including the indexed count of arrays in the beginning...the json output when I use:

```
echo json_encode($relationArray);
```

is like this currently:

```
 {"2":{"id":"4","name":"Albaraa","children":
 {"1":{"id":"5","name":"Sadi","data":  [{"relationTo":"Albaraa","relation":"Father"}]}}}}
```

With the "2" and "1" in front of what the first 2 arrays are...which is not what I am trying to achieve which would be like this:

```
 {"id":"4","name":"Albaraa","children":
 {"id":"5","name":"Sadi","data":  [{"relationTo":"Albaraa","relation":"Father"}]}}}}
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: The only reason you can have two ids indexes (4 and 5) is because they are located into 2 different indexes (2 and 1), otherwise one would overwrite the other

Comment: I don't see you doing a `reset($relations);` on the array or an `unset($rel);` before iterating through the results. Does the pointer in the array need to be reset? I'm not sure I follow why you're not using a $key => $value array and expect it not to use the numeric index like it is instead of "id" like you want for the $key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several solutions

1) Do not enter values by `[$i]`, prepare new complete inner array and put it inside with array_push

2) If you still want to do this way you can extract just the values:

`print_r(json_encode(array_values($array)));`